# PDO Connection Error returns object(PDO)#1 (0) { }

Tags: mysql, pdo, php

Did a var_dump - returned `object(PDO)#1 (0) { }`

Code for my database connection below:

```
<?php

$config['db'] = array

    (

        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'dbname'    => 'journal',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => ''


    );


        $dbc = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db']['dbname'], $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']);
        var_dump($dbc);

?>
```

When I try to use the $dbc variable it returns the errors below:

> Notice: Undefined variable: dbc in C:\xampp\htdocs\journal\data\functions.php on line 21
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\journal\data\functions.php on line 21

Line 21:

```
$appendEntries = $dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM `entries`");
```

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable` means the variable `$dbc` is out of scope in where you are trying to use it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and/16959577#16959577

Comment: They're in the same directory and I have a require 'db.php';

Comment: Still not answered... :S

Comment: Strictly speaking, it shouldn't be answered at all, as this question is not on specific programming problem but about your private code inconsistency, so-called "too localized" and thus not allowed on the site.

Answer (score 2):

I'm imagining your code in `functions.php` looks something like this

```
require_once 'db.php';

function somethingSomethingEntries() {
    $appendEntries = $dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROMentries");
}
```

In the scope of `somethingSomethingEntries`, `$dbc` does not exist. You should pass it in as an argument, eg

```
function somethingSomethingEntries(PDO $dbc) {
    $appendEntries = $dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROMentries");
}
```

and call it with

```
require_once 'db.php';

somethingSomethingEntries($dbc);
```

Comment: Beautiful breakdown. Helped me a ton!